# How to read data from a file into a structure?

Tags: c++

I have a text file that I want to read into a structure.

```
Harry;3.4;3.21;2.83;3.78
Ron;2.89;2.21;2.10;3.33
Hermione;3.65;3.78;4.0;3.89
Dumbledore;2.36;2.75;3.12;3.33
Snape;3.12;2.4;2.78;3.2
```

This is the Student structure.

```
struct Student
{
string name;
double gpa[4];
double averageGPA;
};
```

I have dynamically allocated the Student array and I now want to read in data form the file. Using `getline(infile, pointer[0].name, ';');` will work to get the first name, but I can't read in the numbers. If I use `getline(infile, pointer[0].gpa[0], ';');` I get an error. I think its because `double gpa[4]` is not a string? How would I be able to read in the data for the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

To read integers use `operator>>`

```
getline(infile, pointer[0].name, ';');
for (int loop = 0; loop < 4; ++loop) {
    infile >> pointer[0]. gpa[loop];
    // You now need to read the ';' off the input stream
    // Note the last number is not followed by a ';'
}
```

Not the above code does not do any error detection. You should add that.

It is also usually for a struct/class to define its own input operator.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Student& data)
{
    // do the reading in here.
    return str;
}
```

When you have done that it is easy to read a `stuent` object.

```
int main()
{
    Student   s1;
    std::cin >> s1;
}
```

Comment: @Mark: You are supposed to make a reasonable effort yourself. There must be a 100 questions on that already on the site.

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

## 1) Create an `Student` Extraction Operator

If you're going to stream into an object, C++ provides the extraction operator as a way to encapsulate such functionality. http://msdn.com has a good introduction to extraction operators here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k63a66ec.aspx

But fundamentally your going to want to write one that looks something like this:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& lhs, Student& rhs) {
    lhs >> ws;
    getline(lhs, rhs.name, ';');
    lhs >> rhs.gpa[0];
    rhs.averageGPA = rhs.gpa[0];

    const auto size = sizeof(rhs.gpa) / sizeof(rhs.gpa[0]);

    for(auto i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        lhs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ';');
        lhs >> rhs.gpa[i];
        rhs.averageGPA += rhs.gpa[i];
    }
    rhs.averageGPA /= size;
}
```

## 2) Use `vector<Student>` not a Dynamically Allocated `Student[]`

`vector`s provide numerous advantages over dynamically allocated arrays, not the least of which are range based `for`-loops and `iterator`s.

But after you've written an extraction operator you can also use an [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to construct a `const vector<Student>`. For example:

```
stringstream in{"Harry;3.4;3.21;2.83;3.78\nRon;2.89;2.21;2.10;3.33\nHermione;3.65;3.78;4.0;3.89\nDumbledore;2.36;2.75;3.12;3.33\nSnape;3.12;2.4;2.78;3.2"};
const vector<Student> data{istream_iterator<Student>{in}, istream_iterator<Student>{}};
```

You can see a live example of all this including using `data` in a range based `for`-loop here: http://ideone.com/iAFE9c

## 3) Remove `Student.averageGPA`

`Student.averageGPA` is derived data that should be calculated as needed. Maintaining it as part of `Student` asks for synchronization issues, may invoke unnecessary calculation, and complicates the extraction operator.

You can easily get the average GPA of an initialized `Student s1` like this in C++17:

```
const auto averageGPA = accumulate(cbegin(s1.gpa), cend(s1.gpa), 0.0) / size(s1.gpa);
```

Or this in C++11:

```
const auto size = sizeof(s1.gpa) / sizeof(s1.gpa[0]);
const auto averageGPA = accumulate(s1.gpa, s1.gpa + size, 0.0) / size;
```

But the big thing this does is simplifies your extraction operator:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& lhs, Student& rhs) {
    lhs >> ws;
    getline(lhs, rhs.name, ';');
    lhs >> rhs.gpa[0];

    for(auto i = 1; i < size(rhs.gpa); ++i) {
        lhs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ';');
        lhs >> rhs.gpa[i];
    }
}
```